# EFK stack - do I need to copy the autogenerated *.conf files to implement json parser?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd

I am trying to implement a json parser. Something similar to this

```
<filter kubernetes.**>
   @type parser
   key_name log
   <parse>
      @type json
      json_parser json
   </parse>
</filter>
```

The instructions that I was following suggests that I need to place the above before the <match> section in fluentd.conf.

I guess my question is should I recreate all of the generated *.conf files? There are a lot of *.conf files that are autogenerated (i.e. fluentd.conf, kubernetes.conf, systemd.conf, etc...). I would like to just add the json configuration without having to recreate all of the generated *.conf files but I do not know if this is possible or a best practice. I am new to fluentd so not exactly sure how to go about this.

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to implement a json parser"? Are you writing a custom plugin? Or configuring the parser filter plugin with JSON? As for a filter plugin, it should come before a match section. See the [Life of a fluentd event](https://docs.fluentd.org/quickstart/life-of-a-fluentd-event) for more details.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the "generated config files"? How are these files generated? For reusing a config file, you can use [@include](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#6.-reuse-your-config-the-include-directive).

Comment: Using the efk operator there are autogenerated *.conf files that are created under /fluent/etc. So in order to add the json filter I had to copy all of the autogenerated files out of the pod. Then add them back to an emptydir {} using the configmap and also add my json filter conf.

Comment: Please share the link of the k8s EFK operator you're using.

Comment: I am using [this](https://operatorhub.io/operator/elastic-cloud-eck) operator with a fluentd daemonset.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what I did was go to /fluentd/etc and copy all of the autogenerated files. I then made the above changes to add the json formatting and then I load the modified files as a volume into the /fluentd/etc directory.

1. Copy all of the autogenerated files
2. Add json parser to one of the autogenerated files
3. Load the autogenerated files as a volume back to the fluentd daemonset